# How do I show validation error when users submit the form without selecting anything from the drop-down list in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I have a form with drop-down list. If the user did not select a category and submitted the form, I will get exception. So How do I send validation error from the controller to the view? because I don't want to write JavaScript.

This is the drop-down list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Article.CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name"), "Select Category", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

*I know this way is working but I need that label (Select Category)*

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Article.CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name"), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**All and New controllers:**

```
       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult New(Article article)
        {

            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string FullName = HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                    .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
                    .FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).FullName;

                article.AuthorName = FullName;
                article.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                db.Aricles.Add(article);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("All");
            }
         }

        public ActionResult All()
        {
            var Articles = db.Aricles.ToList();
            return View(Articles);
        }
```

**My model:**

```
  public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to use **[Required]** attribute but I don't know why it does not work. 

This is a screenshot of the exception [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq7st.png)

Comment: Could you please confirm, are you populating the DropdownList values back in action named `All`? Or could you please post the action `All` as well?

Comment: @Tanaka your returning model are different on GET and POST validation failed.

Comment: @KhaksarWeqar I updated the post.

Comment: @MannanBahelim I am thinking about your comment. Still I didn't figure it out.

Comment: I think I got your point about returning different model. The validation is coming from Article Model but in my view it is "@model ArticleCategoryViewModel". @KhaksarWeqar

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue after I thought about the comment written by Mannan Bahelim . I don't get validation error because the model in the view was **ArticleCategoryViewModel** while it should be **Article** model.